# CIM RDF and RDFS

Tags: xml, rdf, rdfs

On .NET platform:

Has any body used RDFS Validation for CIM RDF/XML Files?

Has anybody used RDFS Validation for RDF/XML Files?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question fully as it's quite vague.

RDFS is a schema language for RDF - you can use tools to check whether an RDF Graph conforms to an RDFS schema but that is unrelated to what syntax the RDF is encoded in.

RDFS schemas are not equivalent to XML Schemas which is what your question implies. By this I mean that RDF is not limited to RDF/XML syntax and you would validate the RDF in-memory rather than directly at the syntax level (in fact I'm not sure doing RDFS validation at the syntax level is even possible).

If you want to validate some RDF try looking for Ontology processing tools as these will typically allow RDFS validation, some examples include Pellet, Protege, TopBraid Composer.

Comment: Yes, u are right. RDF graph validation against an RDF Schema in memory. Thanks for the tools. They are all Java based. My question was .NET based. I am going with raw XML based tools for CIM RDF/XML file parsing and validation against in-memory object models (generated from another source).